# False variation title is displayed

Tags: 7, commerce

On my Commerce Kickstart Page, I have each prodcut with 2 different variations. 
My problem is that I am unable to change the variation title for the product variations that have been added first on the product itself. It continuously overrides my changes with the original, auto-generated title for a couple of products, but not all of them. 
The second variation is always called "DVD - Product name" and works fine.

The first is set up like this: 
[image: 1]

When I now click on "Update product", it shows the correct values in the overview of the variations:

[image: 2]

I now simply say "Save" on my edit product view and save the product. I click edit again and the old value is back as the variation title. But when I open the variation settings, it still shows me my changed title in the textfield:

[image: 3]

I already took a look into the database, and the correct value (my changed title) is stored there. This made me think that this is a chaching problem, I played around with cache settings and stuff but that did not change anything.

It may also be noted that this problem does only occur for about 30% of my products, and also only for the first added products.

Comment: If you load product variation, what title is it showing?

Comment: The false (original one). It is shown in the basket and the add to cart form

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you go into a product display and then edit the variations inline from there. To stop this happening go to the manage fields screen for your product display e.g.  "Structure > Content types > Product display > manage fields"

Then click edit on the "Product" field and you should see "Auto generate the product title" tick box. Untick that and it should stop the issue happening going forward

Comment: It is already unticked, otherwise I would not have been able to edit the title in the first place right?

Comment: Whenever i've done it I've always been able to edit the title regardless if thats ticked or not. But when its ticked I was getting what happens to you and whatever I enter for the title gets overwritten to match the product display title. So i'm not sure what else might be going on on your setup

Comment: On my installation, the title field of a variation is not editable until you remove the "Auto generate" option.